# android applicatin can't find jni library when installed as system application

Tags: android, java-native-interface, apk

recently I meet such problem, when I use jni with android application , when the apk is built , the test.so is put in lib/armeabi/ in the apk package , when I install this apk as user application , it can run and find the library when use System.LoadLibrary() to find it . while when I install it in system/app , it can't find the library . anyone meet such kind of problem before and could you tell me how to solve this , thanks very much for any suggestions .

Answer (score 7):

This answer on the Android NDK group seems to have your answer:

http://groups.google.com/group/android-ndk/browse_thread/thread/bfceac612dceae8c/7f2b8b48a87c2a52?show_docid=7f2b8b48a87c2a52

In a nutshell it looks like you cannot do it because `/system` is mounted `read-only` which means that you the APK+library are installed in the factory.

Comment: thanks Cody , I found the solution now , install my application as system application and mount /system as read-write and also put the .so in system/lib , then it can find it . thanks a  lot .